# Django : Export MongoDB with ForeignKeys

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I am using Django with Mongodb,  im trying to export my database like this:

```
./mongoexport -d foo_db -c foo_bar --csv -f "client,name,brand_manager_name,brand_manager_email" -o foo_bar.csv
```

The foreignKey, Client, is blank in the csv file and the email field aswell.

In other exports the datefields are also blank.

How are you supposed to do that?

Comment: I guess that you should write custom django command for that where you can directly export required data to csv or create a temporary collection for that and when use mongoexport.

Comment: Ok, so you mean creating my own CSV from the data, and not using mongoexport?

Comment: Check this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/.